# R: Loop through matrix, delete cells based on criteria

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to loop through a matrix and change cell values to NA if the cell in the prior column is NA.

Its a big matrix with 9 cols and 57772 rows. Tried different for for loops but I can't seem to get it right.

In short, this Matrix.

```
m <- structure(c("X","X","X","X","X","X", NA, "X", "X", NA, NA, "X", "X", NA, NA, "X", "X", 
             NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, "X"), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
               NULL, c("1", "2", "3", "4","5")))
```

should become this

```
      1   2   3   4   5  
[1,] "X" "X" NA  NA  NA
[2,] "X" NA  NA  NA  NA 
[3,] "X" "X" "X" NA  NA 
[4,] "X" "X" NA  NA  NA 
[5,] "X" NA  NA  NA  NA
```

But with this loop

```
for(j in ncol(m):2) m[, j] <- ifelse(is.na(m[, j-1]), NA, m[, j])
```

it only becomes this

```
      1   2   3   4   5  
[1,] "X" "X" NA  NA  "X"
[2,] "X" NA  NA  "X" NA 
[3,] "X" "X" "X" NA  NA 
[4,] "X" "X" NA  NA  NA 
[5,] "X" NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop should suffice here.

```
for(j in 2:ncol(m) m[, j] <- ifelse(is.na(m[, j-1]), NA, m[, j])
```

giving:

```
     1   2   3   4  5 
[1,] "X" "X" NA  NA NA
[2,] "X" NA  NA  NA NA
[3,] "X" "X" "X" NA NA
[4,] "X" "X" NA  NA NA
[5,] "X" NA  NA  NA NA
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
m <- structure(c(NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X"), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("1", "2", "3", "4")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Its not an error. I changed my exmaple to make it more clear: it should change to NA if there isn't an X in the cell on its left.

Comment: In the last row there is not an X in column 2 so according to that rule there should be an NA in column 3 but there is an X in column 3 of that row.

Comment: I see your point, but I've explained it bad it seems. I've visualised it in detail above. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: The part that was not clear was the the prior column did not refer to the column before in the original matrix but the column after it had been changed by the algorithm.  I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks G.G. Much appreciated